# different browsers referencing different css files, arcgis javascript cmv

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, firefox, configurable-map-viewer

When I open a page in chrome, and click on a feature the popup style is coming from one css file, and when I do the same thing in firefox, the popup looks completely different and is referencing a different css. I am very new to developing in javascript and don't know very much yet. Why would this occur? I started out with the CMV template https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app which has a main.css file that is downloaded with the source code, and the index page also references esri.css on the web. I found the popup style was coming from the esri.css and wanted to make some changes, so save it locally and changed my html file to point to the local version. Once I did this, I started getting the funky popup in firefox. How can I correct this? I notice there are some settings for the .esriPopup in the main.css, but when I tried to modify these nothing changed.

Comment: A suggestion: when you ask a question here at gis.stackexchange.com regarding CMV (http://github.com/cmv/cmv-app), please be sure to add the 'cmv' tag. Those of us here that provide support for CMV will be alerted more quickly if the tag is used.

Comment: thanks, there are a lot of tags I still can't use I forget if that is one of them, but i will definitely use it next time if I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you've copied the esri.css file from the js.arcgis.com server to your local server. This won't work because that esri.css file references images and possibly other resources on the js.arcgis.com server. It references those relative to the location of the css file. The css file is on your server but those required images are not on your server so the popup and possibly other things will get "funky".

Your first inclination was correct. Edit the css classes in the main.css file. This will override the same css classes in esri.css. If your modifications do not appear to be working, first check that you've got the syntax correct and then be sure that the files are not cached by your browser.

Here is an online reference to customizing the popup: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_customizepopup.html

Comment: I see. I basically wiped out the esriPopup content in the main and replaced it with what I want, that seemed to work. thanks for your help!